# Why function in my package is not working

Tags: go, package

I have put a small code file in `$GOPATH` which is `~/go/src`. Here I have made a folder `mysrc` and there I have kept a file `mytest.go`, which is as follows:

```
package mytest
import ("fmt")
func myfn(){
  fmt.Println("My own fn")
}
```

I try to import above code with following file:

```
package main
import ("mysrc")
main(){
    myfn()
}
```

When I try to run above file, I get error:

```
# command-line-arguments
./useMyfn.go:3:1: syntax error: non-declaration statement outside function body
```

Where is the problem and how can it be solved? Thanks for your help.

Edit: I corrected the main fn to `func main()` but now the errors are:

```
# command-line-arguments
./useMyfn.go:2:9: imported and not used: "mysrc" as mytest
./useMyfn.go:4:2: undefined: myfn
```

Comment: Ok. I missed it. But even after correcting that, there are errors - pl see edit in my question above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do few things

1. I suggest to use a package name that the name is same with the folder name.
2. The `myfn()` function need to be exported. How to do it: simply set the first character of the function name to uppercase.

```golang
package mysrc // <-- 1

import (
    "fmt"
)

func Myfn() { // <-- 2
    fmt.Println("My own fn")
}
```

3. The `func` keyword is required before `main()` statement.
4. To access a function from other package, you need to write down the package name before the function name. In this context it'll be `mysrc.Myfn()`.

```golang
package main

import (
    "mysrc"
)

func main() { // <-- 3
    mysrc.Myfn() // <-- 4
}
```